# How can I move Steam to an SSD to improve boot time?

Tags: steam

Most of the articles I've found detail how to move Steam games to another disk. That's not what I want to do, I want to move Steam (the application itself) to an SSD in order to improve the time it takes for it to boot.

What are my options here? I have a 64GB SSD and I assume Steam will fit on it, but my games certainly won't. How can I go about doing this in the simplest manner possible?

Comment: I believe this is just a matter of specifying the path at Steam install time and then in Steam settings post-install, putting your Steam library on another drive.

Comment: Are there any other complications that could occur as a result? Lost settings and what not?

Comment: I've never done much configuration of Steam itself, but I imagine many if not most of the settings are stored with your account. Just install Steam on a different drive and then point the steam application to the already existing Steam Library.

Comment: Uninstall Steam and reinstall it on your SSD.

Comment: To really improve boot times you need to install Windows on your SSD, though 64GB will be a tight fit with the newer versions of Windows.

Comment: You may want to read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/574686/… as a prevent you from boning yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just putting the Steam executable on the SSD, and not the games, will not noticeably improve your load time ('boot time' is typically reserved for your OS/computer). The Steam executable has very little data to load compared to a modern game, so the decreased load time from hard drive to RAM will hardly (if at all) be noticeable.

If you still want to do that, simply uninstall Steam and reinstall it, giving the installer the path to your SSD. If you don't want your games on the same drive, you'll have to create another library directory on a different drive when installing your games. Ideally, you'd leave your games where they are and just point Steam to them. This process is similar to this question: [Is it possible to move a hard drive with Steam games to a new computer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197001/is-it-possible-to-move-a-hard-drive-with-steam-games-to-a-new-computer)